# python thread communication with angular using flask socketio

Tags: python, angular, multithreading, flask, flask-socketio

I'm currently working on a multithread simulation app in Python communicating with an Angular frontend server using flask_socketio. The simulation represents a graph problem where each node is a thread. I want a thread to send a message to the frontend, in real time, each time there is an update in a node, but instead I receive all messages at once after all threads are done

main.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

from Services.runSimulation import SimThread

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'vnkdjnfjknfl1232#'
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")
CORS(app)


@socketio.on('begin')
def beginSimulation(message, methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print(message)
    socketio.emit('message_log', {'message': 'Simulation started.'})
    threads = []

    for node in Example.vect:
        if node not in Example.exits and node.id not in Example.blocked:
            thread = SimThread(node, barrier, socket)
            thread.start()
            threads.append(thread)
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
    socketio.emit('message_log', {'message': 'Simulation complete.'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

simulation.py

```
class SimThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, node, barrier, socket):
        super().__init__()
        self.node = node
        self.capacity = node.capacity
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.barrier = barrier
        self.socket = socket

    def run(self):
        self.barrier.wait()
        while population > 0:
            # run the simulation
            ...
            # when I find a result, I lock the resources and I want to send details to angular
            # I'm using a sleep with different times for each node
            self.socket.sleep(self.node.cost)
            with self.lock:
                self.socket.emit('message_log', {'from': self.node.id,
                                                    'to': best_route.id,
                                                    'pop': str(move_amount)})
```

Angular service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RequestsService {

  constructor(private socket:Socket) { }
  testpost() {
    this.socket.emit('begin', 'msg from ang');
  }
  receive():Observable<any> {
    return this.socket.fromEvent('message_log')
  }

}
```

Issue is that instead of receiving a message in angular in real time when I call self.socket.emit in simulation.py, I receive all messages at once when all threads are finished. I'm guessing this is because I'm also blocking the main thread? I tried using asyncio but couldn't manage to make it work.

Comment: What async mode are you using with Flask-SocketIO? You should use `threading`, preferably. If you use eventlet or gevent, then you have to monkey-patch the standard library so that the threading functions become non-blocking.

Comment: I'm using threading in the simulation and I did try using asyncio with socketio.run. Do you mean that I should put socketio.run in a thread? I'm new with flask and multithreading with sockets, so I'm not sure what you mean with "What async mode are you using with Flask-SocketIO?". Could you please explain?

Comment: Please share the output of `pip freeze` to see what you have in there. If you don't know what the Flask-SocketIO async mode is, then you are letting the package pick a mode based on your installed packages.

Comment: I added the output to this ideone [link](https://ideone.com/NA1bXO)

Comment: You have eventlet and gevent installed. Flask-SocketIO will prefer eventlet, unless it is told you want to use a different concurrency library. If you are not familiar with async frameworks such as eventlet or gevent I suggest you uninstall them both and then Flask-SocketIO will run with standard threads, which is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
I managed to solve the issue by adding to the SocektIO initialisation the async_mode eventlet and using monkey patch as follows:

```
...
import eventlet

socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*", async_mode='eventlet')
eventlet.monkey_patch()
```